# Why does Cypress 'within' function only search the first child but not all children?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following HTML structure on my website:

```
<body>
 ...
 <div class="main-wrapper">
   <div class="first-child">
      <p>elements belonging to first-child</p>
   </div>
   <div class="second-child">
      <p>elements belonging to second-child</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to use the `within` function of Cypress to scope within the `.main-wrapper` class.
So, I have something like this:

```
cy.get('.main-wrapper').within(() => {
   cy.get('.first-child p').click();      // Cypress can find this
   cy.get('.second-child p').click();     // Cypress cannot find this!
});
```

Apparently, Cypress is only able to find the `.first-child` element but not the `.second-child` element.
But I don't understand why `within` in Cypress can only work with the first child element but not all children in the scoped element.

Cypress has no problem finding them if I remove the `within` block and have them in the global scope like this:

```
   cy.get('.first-child p').click();
   cy.get('.second-child p').click();
```

How should I use `within` so that Cypress can find all children in the scoped element and not just the first child?

**Edit:**

On a second thought, I'm not sure if this will affect the way `within` works but the `.second-child` actually will only be inserted into the DOM after `.first-child` is clicked. In my case, the `.first-child` is indeed being clicked first and so I assume the DOM would already have `.second-child` by the time Cypress attempts to look for `.second-child`, right?

Comment: could you assign what `within` returns to the console output when clicking on it?

Comment: @AlexIzbas I get this in the console when I click on the output: `AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'div.second-child p', but never found it.`

Comment: This looks to be the output for `cy.get('.second-child p')`. Try to wrap the previous yielded subject: `cy.get('.main-wrapper').within(($el) => { ... }` and check the cypress log for `within` command and check the element it wrap/returns in the console. Let's make sure it returns both elements

Comment: @AlexIzbas I have the line wrapped in the `within` callback. When I click on the `within` command, the output shows that it yielded `<div class="main-wrapper"><div class="first-child">...</div></div>`

Comment: @AlexIzbas I'm not sure if this is going to affect how the `within` command works, but the `.second-child` actually will only be inserted into the DOM after `.first-child` is clicked. In my case, the `.first-child` is indeed being clicked first, but I'm starting to think Cypress may not not be aware that the DOM has been updated?

Comment: in case the second element is rendered after clicking on first one then yeah, the yielded subject doesn't have it so assertion fails. However, your attached HTML snippet in the description have them both which makes me curious. In the previous comment you attached the wrapped output from the console: could you expand it and see if the second one is visible or not?

Comment: @AlexIzbas The wrapped output from console only has `.first-child`, it doesn't have `.second-child`. In other words, it seems like even though `.first-child` has been clicked and `.second-child` showed up on the screen, Cypress still cannot detect `.second-child` in the DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216569/discussion-between-alex-izbas-and-carven).

Answer (score 0):

If you run this basic test where `.second` is added 3 seconds after page load, the added `div.second-child` is found.

**HTML fragment**

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div class="first-child">
    <p>elements belonging to first-child</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  setTimeout(() => {

    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.main-wrapper');
    let second = document.createElement("div");
    second.classList.add('second-child')
    wrapper.appendChild(second)

  }, 3000);    // wait within the limit of Cypress' timeout
</script>
```

**Test**

```
it('', ()=> {

  cy.visit('app/within.html')

  cy.get('.main-wrapper').within(() => {
    cy.get('.first-child')
    cy.get('.second-child')  // succeeds
  });
  
})
```

It seems to me the problem would be in the click handler of `.first-child`.